# ProGuard ** wildcard matching classes issue

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-proguard

I am trying to generate a proper proguard build file for my app.

Reading through ProGuard documentation and various examples online I came to the conclusion that this:

```
keep class my.package.data.** { *;}
```

...will go through all the sub-packages in models, and their sub-packages etc., find all classes and keep all their names, fields and methods.

But from the debug output I can see that the methods in classes from subpackages are obfuscated.

What's even puzzling for me is that after adding replacing the above with:

```
keep class my.package.data.models.** { *;}
```

... Methods are not obfuscated.

The class in my example is in a package at `my.package.data.models.user.User`.

**Question:**

I have the impression that the wildcard `**` only goes one sub-package in depth.

But the doc states: `**` matches any part of a class name, possibly containing any number of package separators. For example, * *.Test" matches all Test classes in all packages except the root package. Or, "mypackage.**" matches all classes in "mypackage" and in its sub-packages.

Which doesn't mention inner sub-packages. I don't know if I am getting this right, but what is the correct way to reference all sub-packages and their children etc., if its not `my.package.**`?